# How do I activate the Java class resource lookup cache?

Tags: java

I want to check if the VM property sun.cds.enableSharedLookupCache helps improve the performance of an application that does numerous calls to `ClassLoader::getResource()`. I found that property in `URLClassPath`.
I tried to turn it on with `-Dsun.cds.enableSharedLookupCache=true` or `-Dsun.cds.enableSharedLookupCache` as VM argument but that did not activate the cache.
I use this simple test program to test the activation :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("java/lang/Exception.class"));
    }
}
```

The value of field `lookupCacheEnabled` in `URLClassPath` is false :

```
private static volatile boolean lookupCacheEnabled
    = "true".equals(VM.getSavedProperty("sun.cds.enableSharedLookupCache"));
```

EDIT: jdk version is jdk8

What am I missing here ?

Comment: On which java version you are trying?

Comment: I edit my question : jdk version is jdk8

Comment: Hope this will help: http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/RFR-M-8061651-Interface-to-the-Lookup-Index-Cache-to-improve-URLClassPath-search-time-td204636.html

Comment: Also, check whether you are using OpenJDK or java-hotspot, because flag only present on hotspot JVM based on answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/44339535/2987755

Comment: You can check the `sun.cds.enableSharedLookupCache` flag in all available JVM flags for the java version you are trying.

Comment: it seems that the VM option is -XX:+EnableSharedLookupCache